# not understanding the Suave API, always the same result is returned

Tags: f#, suave

Here is a test:

```
open System
open System.Threading
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Suave
open Suave.Logging
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Writers


let private configuration = {
    defaultConfig with
        bindings   = [ HttpBinding.createSimple HTTP "0.0.0.0" 80 ]
}


let private getServerTime () : WebPart =
    DateTime.UtcNow |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> Successful.OK >=> setMimeType "application/json"


let private webApplication =
    choose
        [
            GET >=> choose
                [
                    path "/servertime"   >=> getServerTime ()
                ]
        ]

let start () =
    let listening, server = startWebServerAsync configuration webApplication
    server    |> Async.Start
    listening |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore


[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    start()

    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)
    0
```

with this example, the getServerTime function is called once and this is it, every subsequent call to the endpoint will return the original result.

I don't understand why? When I use pathScan with parameters, then the function is called each time, as expected, but in this case, with a simple get, only the first call is done while this is defined as a function.

But I don't understand the doc **at all** either (from the flow of the doc, its contents and the overall document structure...), so the answer is probably simple :)

Comment: It's been a very long time since I used Suave, but I believe the answer to your mystery can be found at the bottom of this page: https://suave.io/composing.html  Read from "Your web parts are..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would highly recommend that you study monadic composition. This is a necessary foundation for understanding these things. It will give you an idea of what `>=>` and `>>=` are and how to deal with them.

As for the problem at hand: yes, you defined `getServerTime` as a function, but that kind of doesn't matter, because that function is only called once, during construction of the `webApplication` value.

The structure of the server is such that it's literally a function `HttpContext  -> Async<HttpContext option>`. It gets a request context and returns a modified version of it. And all of those combinators - `choose` and `>=>` and so on - they work with such functions.

The expression `path "/servertime"` is also such function. Literally. You can call it like this:

```
let httpCtx = ...
let newCtxAsync = path "/servertime" httpCtx
```

Moreover, the expression `getServerTime()` is ALSO such function. So you can do:

```
let httpCtx = ...
let newCtxAsync = getServerTime () httpCtx
```

That's what the `WebPart` type is. It's an async function from context to new context.

Now, what the `>=>` operator does is *combine* these functions. Makes them pipe the context from one webpart to the next. That's all.

---

When you wrote your `getServerTime` function, you created a `WebPart` that always returns the same thing. It's kind of like this:

```
let f x y = printf "x = %d" x
let g = f 42
```

Here, `g` is a function (just like a `WebPart` is a function), but whenever it's called, it will always return `"x = 42"`. Why? Because I partially applied that parameter, it's sort of "baked in" in the definition of `g` now. The same way the current time is "baked in" in the `WebPart` that you have created inside `getServerTime`.

If you want a different time to be returned every time, you need to *recreate* the `WebPart` every time. Construct a *new* `WebPart` on every call, one with that call's time baked in. The smallest change to do that is probably this:

```
let private getServerTime () : WebPart =
    let time : WebPart = fun ctx -> (DateTime.UtcNow |> string |> Successful.OK) ctx
    time >=> setMimeType "text/plain"
```

On the surface it may look like the definition of `time` is silly: after all, `let f x = g x` can always be replaced by `let f = g`, right? Well, not always. Only as long as `g` is pure. But your webpart here is not: it depends on the current time.

This way, every time the `time` webpart is "run" (which means it gets a context as a parameter), it will run `DateTime.UtcNow`, then pass it to `Successful.OK`, and then pass the context to the resulting function.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, the problem I had is now very clear and I understand the flow better (not sure about >>= though :)) That brings up something interesting: since I have to recreate the webpart everytime, the "fun ctx-> doSomething ctx" part can be broken by RestSharp which proposes the simplify the lambda.

Comment: The following posts by Scott Wlaschin (F# for Fun and Profit) helped me immensely (in the following order): 1. [railway-oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) and 2. ["elevated world"](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/) series.